# Li-ion cell voltage balancing issue while charging

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, battery-chemistry

I have  a two cell li-ion battery which has specifications of 7.4v, 2200mAH. I used one cell (3.7v, 2200mAH) for a required project. I discharged it and then reconfigured in to series(7.4v, 2200mAH) again and charged up(charge voltage of my circuit is 8.4v). It is not drawing sufficient charge current and finally only  1 cell is getting full charge voltage of 4.2v, other one remains low voltage(2.7v). So is there any problem of charging with two cell having different level of voltage.

Comment: The charger may be refusing to charge something as low as 2.7, considering it undervoltage. Try charging that one manually with a low current to 3.something. If it still won't take a charge, it's damaged. If it does charge, then try it on your balance charger again.

Comment: You should not charge an unbalanced series arrangement of lithium ion batteries without a circuit designed specifically to do so, and ideally you should start with matched batteries (matched voltage, matched brand, model, ratings, use history)